# Pyspark: pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)

Tags: python, pyspark, pyarrow

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df.show(5, False)
+------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+--------+
|ID                                  |timestamp          |accuracy|lat    |lon     |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+--------+
|00000059-eb17-4db6-8e46-0739205a7ca1|2020-01-01 11:51:43|1.0     |41.3128|-81.8566|
|00000387-5804-40b2-9196-5cfead4dc55b|2020-01-01 18:05:24|11.7    |29.4241|-98.4936|
|00000387-5804-40b2-9196-5cfead4dc55b|2020-01-01 20:11:23|15.7    |29.4241|-98.4936|
|00000387-5804-40b2-9196-5cfead4dc55b|2020-01-01 18:05:10|14.4    |29.4241|-98.4936|
|00000387-5804-40b2-9196-5cfead4dc55b|2020-01-01 18:06:02|12.4    |29.4241|-98.4936|
+------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+--------+
```

If I run a code keeping the `ID` column I get this error

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
```

Answer (score 4):

This kind of errors usually come from unmatched return type .

For example , happens when convert python int to pyspark StringType like below :

```py
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("a", StringType(), True),
        StructField("b", StringType(), True),
        StructField("c", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("d", IntegerType(), True),
    ]
)

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def test(pdf):
    return pd.DataFrame([range(4)], columns=['a','b','c','d'])

some_df.groupby(xxx).apply(test)
```

Also happen on datetime/date to StringType , so I assume this kind of error come from unmatched return type . You should review your code .

As your case , I think there may be some nan-string values in ID column .

Comment: I had this issue when I mis-specified a field in the schema as StringType. It is supposed to be a DoubleType.